# adding autoplay to jquery.roundabout

Tags: javascript, autoplay

I have a site I am working on that uses the roundabout from fredhq.com and I would like to make it so it auto plays, I have had a look on their website and can not work out where I need to add the relevant auto play code!

Here is the jquery.roundabout.js code:

```
 // creates a default shape to be used for pathing
jQuery.extend({
    roundabout_shape: {
        def: 'lazySusan',
        lazySusan: function(r, a, t) {
            return {
                x: Math.sin(r + a), 
                y: (Math.sin(r + 3*Math.PI/2 + a) / 8) * t, 
                z: (Math.cos(r + a) + 1) / 2,
                scale: (Math.sin(r + Math.PI/2 + a) / 2) + 0.5
            };
        }
    }
});

jQuery.fn.roundabout = function() {
    var options = (typeof arguments[0] != 'object') ? {} : arguments[0];

    // set options and fill in defaults
    options = {
        bearing: (typeof options.bearing == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.bearing % 360.0),
        tilt: (typeof options.tilt == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.tilt),
        minZ: (typeof options.minZ == 'undefined') ? 100 : parseInt(options.minZ, 10),
        maxZ: (typeof options.maxZ == 'undefined') ? 400 : parseInt(options.maxZ, 10),
        minOpacity: (typeof options.minOpacity == 'undefined') ? 0.40 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.minOpacity),
        maxOpacity: (typeof options.maxOpacity == 'undefined') ? 1.00 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.maxOpacity),
        minScale: (typeof options.minScale == 'undefined') ? 0.40 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.minScale),
        maxScale: (typeof options.maxScale == 'undefined') ? 1.00 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.maxScale),
        duration: (typeof options.duration == 'undefined') ? 600 : parseInt(options.duration, 10),
        btnNext: options.btnNext || null,
        btnPrev: options.btnPrev || null,
        easing: options.easing || 'swing',
        clickToFocus: (options.clickToFocus !== false),
        focusBearing: (typeof options.focusBearing == 'undefined') ? 0.0 : jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(options.focusBearing % 360.0),
        shape: options.shape || 'lazySusan',
        debug: options.debug || false,
        childSelector: options.childSelector || 'li',
        startingChild: (typeof options.startingChild == 'undefined') ? null : parseInt(options.startingChild, 10),
        reflect: (typeof options.reflect == 'undefined' || options.reflect === false) ? false : true
    };

    // assign things 
    this.each(function(i) {
        var ref = jQuery(this);
        var period = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(360.0 / ref.children(options.childSelector).length);
        var startingBearing = (options.startingChild === null) ? options.bearing : options.startingChild * period;

        // set starting styles
        ref
            .addClass('roundabout-holder')
            .css('padding', 0)
            .css('position', 'relative')
            .css('z-index', options.minZ);

        // set starting options
        ref.data('roundabout', {
            'bearing': startingBearing,
            'tilt': options.tilt,
            'minZ': options.minZ,
            'maxZ': options.maxZ,
            'minOpacity': options.minOpacity,
            'maxOpacity': options.maxOpacity,
            'minScale': options.minScale,
            'maxScale': options.maxScale,
            'duration': options.duration,
            'easing': options.easing,
            'clickToFocus': options.clickToFocus,
            'focusBearing': options.focusBearing,
            'animating': 0,
            'childInFocus': -1,
            'shape': options.shape,
            'period': period,
            'debug': options.debug,
            'childSelector': options.childSelector,
            'reflect': options.reflect
        });

        // bind click events
        if (options.clickToFocus === true) {
            ref.children(options.childSelector).each(function(i) {
                jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
                    var degrees = (options.reflect === true) ? 360.0 - (period * i) : period * i;
                    degrees = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(degrees);
                    if (!jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(ref, degrees)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
                            ref.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(degrees);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // bind next buttons
        if (options.btnNext) {
            jQuery(options.btnNext).bind('click.roundabout', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
                    ref.roundabout_animateToNextChild();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

        // bind previous buttons
        if (options.btnPrev) {
            jQuery(options.btnPrev).bind('click.roundabout', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (ref.data('roundabout').animating === 0) {
                    ref.roundabout_animateToPreviousChild();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    });

    // start children
    this.roundabout_startChildren();

    // callback once ready
    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
        setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
    }

    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_startChildren = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        var ref = jQuery(this);
        var data = ref.data('roundabout');
        var children = ref.children(data.childSelector);

        children.each(function(i) {
            var degrees = (data.reflect === true) ? 360.0 - (data.period * i) : data.period * i;

            // apply classes and css first
            jQuery(this)
                .addClass('roundabout-moveable-item')
                .css('position', 'absolute');

            // then measure
            jQuery(this).data('roundabout', {
                'startWidth': jQuery(this).width(),
                'startHeight': jQuery(this).height(),
                'startFontSize': parseInt(jQuery(this).css('font-size'), 10),
                'degrees': degrees
            });
        });

        ref.roundabout_updateChildPositions();
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_setTilt = function(newTilt) {
    this.each(function(i) {
        jQuery(this).data('roundabout').tilt = newTilt;
        jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
    });

    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
        setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
    }

    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_setBearing = function(newBearing) {
    this.each(function(i) {
        jQuery(this).data('roundabout').bearing = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(newBearing % 360, 2);
        jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
    });

    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
        setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
    }

    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_adjustBearing = function(delta) {
    delta = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
    if (delta !== 0) {
        this.each(function(i) {
            jQuery(this).data('roundabout').bearing = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) + delta;
            jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
        });
    }

    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
        setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
    }

    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_adjustTilt = function(delta) {
    delta = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
    if (delta !== 0) {
        this.each(function(i) {
            jQuery(this).data('roundabout').tilt = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(jQuery(this).roundabout_get('tilt') + delta);
            jQuery(this).roundabout_updateChildPositions();
        });
    }

    if (typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[1], ref = this;
        setTimeout(function() { callback(ref); }, 0);
    }

    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToBearing = function(bearing) {
    bearing = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(bearing);
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var duration    = (typeof arguments[1] == 'undefined') ? null : arguments[1];
    var easingType  = (typeof arguments[2] == 'undefined') ? null : arguments[2];
    var passedData  = (typeof arguments[3] !== 'object')   ? null : arguments[3];

    this.each(function(i) {
        var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout'), timer, easingFn, newBearing;
        var thisDuration = (duration === null) ? data.duration : duration;
        var thisEasingType = (easingType !== null) ? easingType : data.easing || 'swing';

        if (passedData === null) {
            passedData = {
                timerStart: currentTime,
                start: jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(ref),
                totalTime: thisDuration
            };
        }
        timer = currentTime - passedData.timerStart;

        if (timer < thisDuration) {
            data.animating = 1;

            if (typeof jQuery.easing.def == 'string') {
                easingFn = jQuery.easing[thisEasingType] || jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def];
                newBearing = easingFn(null, timer, passedData.start, bearing - passedData.start, passedData.totalTime);
            } else {
                newBearing = jQuery.easing[thisEasingType]((timer / passedData.totalTime), timer, passedData.start, bearing - passedData.start, passedData.totalTime);
            }

            ref.roundabout_setBearing(newBearing, function() { ref.roundabout_animateToBearing(bearing, thisDuration, thisEasingType, passedData); });
        } else {
            bearing = (bearing < 0) ? bearing + 360 : bearing % 360;
            data.animating = 0;
            ref.roundabout_setBearing(bearing);
        }
    }); 
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToDelta = function(delta) {
    var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2];
    this.each(function(i) {
        delta = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) + jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(delta);
        jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToBearing(delta, duration, easing);
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToChild = function(childPos) {  
    var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2]; 
    this.each(function(i) {
        var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout');
        if (data.childInFocus !== childPos && data.animating === 0) {       
            var child = jQuery(ref.children(data.childSelector)[childPos]);
            ref.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus(child.data('roundabout').degrees, duration, easing);
        }
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild = function(passedArgs, which) {
    var duration = passedArgs[0], easing = passedArgs[1];
    this.each(function(i) {
        var data     = jQuery(this).data('roundabout');
        var bearing  = jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(360.0 - jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)));
        var period   = data.period, j = 0, range;
        var reflect  = data.reflect;
        var length   = jQuery(this).children(data.childSelector).length;

        bearing = (reflect === true) ? bearing % 360.0 : bearing;

        if (data.animating === 0) {
            // if we're not reflecting and we're moving to next or
            //    we are reflecting and we're moving previous
            if ((reflect === false && which === 'next') || (reflect === true && which !== 'next')) {
                bearing = (bearing === 0) ? 360 : bearing;

                // counterclockwise
                while (true && j < length) {
                    range = { lower: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * j), upper: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * (j + 1)) };
                    range.upper = (j == length - 1) ? 360.0 : range.upper;  // adjust for javascript being bad at floats

                    if (bearing <= range.upper && bearing > range.lower) {
                        jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(bearing - range.lower, duration, easing);
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            } else {
                // clockwise
                while (true) {
                    range = { lower: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * j), upper: jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(period * (j + 1)) };
                    range.upper = (j == length - 1) ? 360.0 : range.upper;  // adjust for javascript being bad at floats

                    if (bearing >= range.lower && bearing < range.upper) {
                        jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(bearing - range.upper, duration, easing);
                        break;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToNextChild = function() {  
    return this.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild(arguments, 'next');
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateToPreviousChild = function() {  
    return this.roundabout_animateToNearbyChild(arguments, 'previous');
};

// moves a given angle to the focus by the shortest means possible
jQuery.fn.roundabout_animateAngleToFocus = function(target) {
    var duration = arguments[1], easing = arguments[2];
    this.each(function(i) {
        var delta = jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(jQuery(this)) - target;
        delta = (Math.abs(360.0 - delta) < Math.abs(0.0 - delta)) ? 360.0 - delta : 0.0 - delta;
        delta = (delta > 180) ? -(360.0 - delta) : delta;

        if (delta !== 0) {
            jQuery(this).roundabout_animateToDelta(delta, duration, easing);    
        }
    });
    return this;
};

jQuery.fn.roundabout_updateChildPositions = function() {
    this.each(function(i) {
        var ref = jQuery(this), data = ref.data('roundabout');
        var inFocus = -1;
        var info = {
            bearing: jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(ref),
            tilt: data.tilt,
            stage: { width: Math.floor(ref.width() * 0.9), height: Math.floor(ref.height() * 0.9) },
            animating: data.animating,
            inFocus: data.childInFocus,
            focusBearingRad: jQuery.roundabout_degToRad(data.focusBearing),
            shape: jQuery.roundabout_shape[data.shape] || jQuery.roundabout_shape[jQuery.roundabout_shape.def]
        };
        info.midStage = { width: info.stage.width / 2, height: info.stage.height / 2 };
        info.nudge = { width: info.midStage.width + info.stage.width * 0.05, height: info.midStage.height + info.stage.height * 0.05 };
        info.zValues = { min: data.minZ, max: data.maxZ, diff: data.maxZ - data.minZ };
        info.opacity = { min: data.minOpacity, max: data.maxOpacity, diff: data.maxOpacity - data.minOpacity };
        info.scale = { min: data.minScale, max: data.maxScale, diff: data.maxScale - data.minScale };

        // update child positions
        ref.children(data.childSelector).each(function(i) {
            if (jQuery.roundabout_updateChildPosition(jQuery(this), ref, info, i) && info.animating === 0) {
                inFocus = i;
                jQuery(this).addClass('roundabout-in-focus');
            } else {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('roundabout-in-focus');
            }
        });

        // update status of who is in focus
        if (inFocus !== info.inFocus) {
            jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent(ref, info.inFocus, 'blur');

            if (inFocus !== -1) {
                jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent(ref, inFocus, 'focus');
            }

            data.childInFocus = inFocus;
        }
    }); 
    return this;    
};

//----------------

jQuery.roundabout_getBearing = function(el) {
    return jQuery.roundabout_toFloat(el.data('roundabout').bearing) % 360;
};

jQuery.roundabout_degToRad = function(degrees) {
    return (degrees % 360.0) * Math.PI / 180.0;
};

jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus = function(el, target) {
    return (jQuery.roundabout_getBearing(el) % 360 === (target % 360));
};

jQuery.roundabout_triggerEvent = function(el, child, eventType) {
    return (child < 0) ? this : jQuery(el.children(el.data('roundabout').childSelector)[child]).trigger(eventType);
};

jQuery.roundabout_toFloat = function(number) {
    number = Math.round(parseFloat(number) * 1000) / 1000;
    return parseFloat(number.toFixed(2));
};

jQuery.roundabout_updateChildPosition = function(child, container, info, childPos) {
    var ref = jQuery(child), data = ref.data('roundabout'), out = [];
    var rad = jQuery.roundabout_degToRad((360.0 - ref.data('roundabout').degrees) + info.bearing);

    // adjust radians to be between 0 and Math.PI * 2
    while (rad < 0) {
        rad = rad + Math.PI * 2;
    }
    while (rad > Math.PI * 2) {
        rad = rad - Math.PI * 2;
    }

    var factors = info.shape(rad, info.focusBearingRad, info.tilt); // obj with x, y, z, and scale values

    // correct
    factors.scale = (factors.scale > 1) ? 1 : factors.scale;
    factors.adjustedScale = (info.scale.min + (info.scale.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(4);
    factors.width = (factors.adjustedScale * data.startWidth).toFixed(4);
    factors.height = (factors.adjustedScale * data.startHeight).toFixed(4);

    // alter item
    ref
        .css('left', ((factors.x * info.midStage.width + info.nudge.width) - factors.width / 2.0).toFixed(1) + 'px')
        .css('top', ((factors.y * info.midStage.height + info.nudge.height) - factors.height / 2.0).toFixed(1) + 'px')
        .css('width', factors.width + 'px')
        .css('height', factors.height + 'px')
        .css('opacity', (info.opacity.min + (info.opacity.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(2))
        .css('z-index', Math.round(info.zValues.min + (info.zValues.diff * factors.z)))
        .css('font-size', (factors.adjustedScale * data.startFontSize).toFixed(2) + 'px')
        .attr('current-scale', factors.adjustedScale);

    if (container.data('roundabout').debug === true) {
        out.push('<div style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 10px; padding: 2px; width: ' + ref.css('width') + '; background-color: #ffc;">');
        out.push('<strong style="font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;">Child ' + childPos + '</strong><br />');
        out.push('<strong>left:</strong> ' + ref.css('left') + '<br /><strong>top:</strong> ' + ref.css('top') + '<br />');
        out.push('<strong>width:</strong> ' + ref.css('width') + '<br /><strong>opacity:</strong> ' + ref.css('opacity') + '<br />');
        out.push('<strong>z-index:</strong> ' + ref.css('z-index') + '<br /><strong>font-size:</strong> ' + ref.css('font-size') + '<br />');
        out.push('<strong>scale:</strong> ' + ref.attr('current-scale'));
        out.push('</div>');

        ref.html(out.join(''));
    }

    return jQuery.roundabout_isInFocus(container, ref.data('roundabout').degrees);
};
```

Many thanks in advance for any help and advice.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

The source you posted doesn't seem to be the latest version of Roundabout.

I just tried with the latest version, and it works perfectly:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul').roundabout({ 
         autoplay: true,
         autoplayDuration: 1000,
         autoplayPauseOnHover: true
      });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/SfAuF/ for an example.

Download the latest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/fredhq/roundabout/zipball/v2.4.2).

Comment: Cheers for your response Adam, I will get the latest version and try it. Phil

Comment: Right, I have downloaded the latest version, but it seems to mess some of my other CSS up and none of the current CSS for the roundabout works, any idea's?  Cheers, Phil

Comment: On my original I have another class in the CSS - .roundabout-moveable-item img and the following - #prew_img  not sure if these have anything to do with it?